# What does the 70 value represent for Android SMS Status?

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I have some Android code in Kotlin that is getting the status of a stored SMS message:

```
val status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.STATUS))
```

Later on, I compare this value to the different constants to see what the status means:

```
print(when (status) {
    Telephony.Sms.STATUS_COMPLETE -> "complete"
    Telephony.Sms.STATUS_FAILED -> "failed"
    Telephony.Sms.STATUS_NONE -> "none"
    Telephony.Sms.STATUS_PENDING -> "pending"
    else -> status.toString()
})
```

Usually, I get strings like "complete", "none" and "pending". However, sometimes "70" is returned, which means that the status doesn't match any of the constants [found listed here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#STATUS_COMPLETE). What does 70 mean here?

Comment: its `STATUS_FAILED` with additional bits 1 (00000010) and 2 (00000100) set

Comment: @pskink post it as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 3):

After digging in the source code (specifically class `SmsMessage`, field `status`) I found out this [document](https://www.arib.or.jp/english/html/overview/doc/STD-T63V12_00/5_Appendix/Rel13/23/23040-d10.pdf). When you scroll to section 9.2.3.15, page 68, you will see list of possible status codes for SMS. Your code (70) means

> 1000110 SM Validity Period Expired

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, this error code is returned when the carrier determines that it is impossible to route the SMS and the message has to be dropped as it is being looped between platforms.

Error code : 70

Destination permanently unavailable The destination (i.e., “dst”)
phone number is not active and there is no indication of when it will become available again. Note that this is a broad error code where the carrier has not indicated the reason for the destination unavailability. Check the “dst” phone number to ensure that it is correct. Also, try sending messages to an alternative number to ensure that all other parts of your application are working.

These are the other error code.

```
    /** TP-Status: no status received. */
    public static final int STATUS_NONE = -1;
    /** TP-Status: complete. */
    public static final int STATUS_COMPLETE = 0;
    /** TP-Status: pending. */
    public static final int STATUS_PENDING = 32;
    /** TP-Status: failed. */
    public static final int STATUS_FAILED = 64;
```